# hide "DEBUG SESSION ENDED" xdebug

Tags: debugging, netbeans, xdebug

I just successfully configured Netbeans to work with xdebug, but when I do finish current session, another browser window with `XDEBUG_SESSION_STOP_NO_EXEC=netbeans-xdebug` url opens and says:

> DEBUG SESSION ENDED

which is annoying.

Where to disable this feature? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

The best solution/workaround I found was right-click on the Project -> Properties -> Run Configuration -> Advanced Button -> Set it to 'Do Not Open Web Browser'.  That's fine for me as I didn't want it to open a browser when starting the debug session either, as most often I wasn't debugging the homepage anyway.